# Entity Framework Code First Optional Property is mapped as Required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an issue with Code First. I just migrate the project from Model First to Code First and I think that Entity Framework is losing its mind... Here is my class (simplified) :

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Key, other properties...

    public bool? MyNullBoolean { get; set; }

    public static void Configure(EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass> myClass)
    {
        // Other configuration on other properties...
        myClass.Property(m => m.MyNullBoolean).IsOptional();
    }
}
```

Here are some additionnal informations for you :

- I call the `Configure()` method in the `OnModelCreating()` method.
- Migrations are enabled and Automatic mode is set to false
- In my migration I have `MyNullBoolean = c.Boolean(nullable: false)`, so EF
  is acting like this property is required, wich is not as previously
  seen.
- I target an existing DB (dev) with data inside so I can't perform Migration "for testing purposes"
- This is the exact same model as the one from Model First and that last one is working correctly...

Here is what I tried :

- Disabling / Enabling EF on the project (deleting Migrations in project and db)
- Restarting VS
- Targeting another DB (same structure)
- Leave the property unconfigured (so EF do the job alone)

I'm out of idea and I found nothing in the Internet. Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: What is the meaning of the comment above the `MyNullBoolean` property? It suggest that the `Key` attribute is applied to it?

Comment: @DavidG no. It's just to say that there are other properties in that class

Comment: Some questions:
1.Are you sure in your db MyNullBoolean is type which allow null?
2.Did you try run program without configuration this property? Which error?

Comment: @Chase yes I'm sure, I checked multiple times and the db was already there before the migration from Model First.

Comment: okay, what about the second question?

Comment: @Chase oh you edited your comment, sorry I didn't see it. I already tried to leave the property unconfigured, and I have `The field "MyNullBoolean" is required` when I use my app.

Comment: Very strange, because if don't use Configure, it must work by convention.
And if U want say to EF do it programmaticly, you add your Configure method. I think problem is still in db (column type etc.), because MyNullBoolean = c.Boolean(nullable: false). Or in instance of your parameter (myClass). I hope it helps. Add solution of problem, when you solve it, just interesting)

Comment: I managed to fix that, please see my answer below. Thanks for the help anyway guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that EF was corrupted because when I uninstall it, clean the solution, install it, rebuild the solution, it worked.

So there was no problem with db or my model.